# How to blur specific parts of an image as defined by x,y coordinates?

Tags: javascript, html, image, svg, canvas

I know HTML's `filter: blur(5px)` can blur the entire image with a blur radius of `5px`. What if I want to blur only a specific part of an image? Like a blur pen, which works only on a specific area of an image. How can I do that?

I have layers of `svg` as shown in the screenshot below
[image]

For example, if you see the image below, specific parts of an image are blurred. How can I do that?
[image]

Comment: What about putting the filter on a rect which has size and position?

Comment: What are the criteria that define "specific parts"?

Comment: And anything you do with CSS won't be secure. Is that a concern?

Comment: @isherwood User could draw a rectangular area (coordinates) that needs a blur.

Comment: @isherwood Nope, that should be okay.